# after removing the vertical black bars from youtube embedded video, the video is taking more than 100vh

Tags: html, css, youtube-api

I have used an embedded YouTube video on my html. Then some vertical black bar (right and left) has appeared. So I have fixed that by doing this

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But after that, the video is taking more than 100vh height, which I don't want.

How can I keep the height 100vh and vanish the vertical bar as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `max-height` attribute instead of `min-height` attribute and erase `height:0;` I think you don't need that when the other height attributes exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the padding-bottom, but if you do, you can consider using the box-sizing property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: It is a hack to maintain the aspect ratio  of the video. so 9/16 * 100 is 56.25.

I need this because if I remove this, on larger screen two black border is appeared so that the video is not touch the edges. now what I want  is made sure that the height of the video is maximum 100vh. not more that that. but the problem is on larger screen the video become more than 100vh in size. here is an example: https://codepen.io/AshiqCSEWorld/pen/jOYreap
resize the window you will see the bottom address bar will not present in 100vh area